# Spring Cloud Vault is not working with custom mount

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

In local machine, I ran Vault server with default policy and wrote the following key value.

```
vault write secret/my-application username=Test
```

**bootstrap.yml (Working)**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-application
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: sometoken
      host: localhost
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      #uri: http://localhost:8200
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      config:
        order: -10
```

I was able to fetch the value using Spring Cloud Vault i.e. when I use default mount (secret). But If I hit the QA server with the custom mount(group) I am getting the following error.

**org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 secret/group/grouptype/groupname/DB: permission denied**

(Not sure why secret is prefixed)

**bootstrap.yml (Not working)**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: group/grouptype/groupname/DB
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: sometoken
      host: 10.20.30.40
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      #uri: http://10.20.30.40:8200
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      config:
        order: -10
```

But if I hit the API from POSTMAN it is working as expected.

```
GET
http://10.20.30.40:8200/v1/group/grouptype/groupname/DB
Header:  
X-Vault-Token:sometoken
```

How to make custom proxy work with Spring boot application. How to exclude secret from the context

Answer (score 0):

For a custom mount, we have to add  **generic**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: grouptype/groupname/DB
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: sometoken
      generic:
        enabled: true
        backend: group
        default-conext: grouptype/groupname/DB 
      host: 10.20.30.40
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      #uri: http://10.20.30.40:8200
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      config:
        order: -10
```

Here "group" is the mount name